# Is the second derivative ($\ddot{r}$) equivalent to the first derivative squared ($\dot{r}^2$)?

Tags: derivatives, notation

Is $\ddot{r}$ equivalent to $\dot{r}^2$?

When using Leibniz's notation I would write this as:

$
\begin{align}
\ddot{r} &= \frac{d^2 r}{dt^2} \\
\dot{r}^2 &= \left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)^2 = \frac{d r^2}{dt^2}\\
\end{align}
$

So at first glance these are not in fact equal. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. You can easily find counterexamples.

Comment: Thank you so much! I looked for a possible duplicate question but perhaps wasn't searching for the right words.

Comment: Please read the "yes" comment above critically since the OP title and body ask opposite questions. The second derivative and squared first derivative are **not** generally equal. The answer to the title as it stands is 'no'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only certain functions $r(t)$ have the two equal. These are precisely the solutions of the ODE
$$\ddot{r}=\dot{r}^2, $$
which are
$$r(t)=C_1-\log(t+C_2). $$

Answer (score 1):

Take $r(t)=t^2$.

Then $\dot{r}^2 = 4t^2$ but $\ddot{r} = 2.$